# Software for storing contacts

Tags: contact-manager

Is there a good cross-platform software in which you can store contacts (phone numbers, mails etc.)?

- It is essential to be at least compatible with Linux.
- It can be web-based although it is not a requirement
- I want it to be free.
- I need it for basic handling of the contacts i.e. just storing them and searching them effectively.
- Plus features would be if it is opensource and if it can sync the contacts between desktops and phones.

Comment: Have you checked the related questions listed next to yours, e.g. [Lightweight contact manager for Linux](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19675/185)? As for web-based, cross-platform and cross-device-sync, [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) would be worth a look. I'm using that for contacts and calendars on Linux and Android (see e.g. [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/26107/185)).

Comment: @Izzy I have seen the first one but I didn't know that ownCloud had such capabilities. :)

Comment: Oh, it definitely has. That and more. And even more considering 3rd party OC apps. So would that be acceptable to you? Shall I write up an answer recommending ownCloud?

Comment: @Izzy Yes sure. After you post your answer I will let one day pass in case someone else has other recommendations and then if that doesn't happen I will accept yours. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime! And in case you didn't know: if you change your mind and decide for another solution, you can move the checkmark anytime :)

Comment: @Izzy I know it as I am a long time SE user, I just don't like changing my vote...It just seems rude. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using **[ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/)** for this and for more. It should fit your requirements just fine:

- **compatible with Linux:** Definitely. For several distributions there are even packages (e.g. `.deb`), or you can chose the manual install from a tarball (often more up-to-date; I prefer this e.g. for my BananaPi running Debian)
- **web-based:** Yes. Requires PHP and a database. By default ships with SQLite (fine for a simple installation for a few users), but you can also use it with MySQL/MariaDB (which I use) or PostgreSQL.
- **free:** Free as "free beer" ***and*** "free speech" (open-source)
- **basic handling of the contacts:** Sure. Plus calendars, plus files, plus other documents (integrates e.g. an editor, a photo gallery, and more).
- **opensource:** Yes.
- **can sync the contacts between desktops and phones:** Yes, that's what I mainly use it for. See [my answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/26107/185) for details on Linux+Android. As it uses CalDAV/CardDAV standards, it should work fine with other systems as well.

Comment: I've been using ownCloud for a long time now and highly recommend it, I would like to point out though that the ownCloud instance can only be run on Linux (like) OS's (not Windows even though it's written in PHP) but the client can be run almost anywhere.

Comment: @Tom I've only used it on Linux so far. But it [is possible to have the server running on Windows](https://ittutorials.net/linux/owncloud/installing-owncloud-in-a-windows-server/), even with IIS. Or that tutorial is wrong :)

Comment: Hmm, that would be great, I've never used IIS but I tried installing it through XAMPP & WAMP but it wouldn't even get to the install screen (encountered loads of errors). I know they've been very public about [8.1 not being compatiable](https://owncloud.org/blog/owncloud-server-8-1-will-not-support-windows-as-server-platform-natively/) but maybe with IIS it works, I see that the guide was written this year and 8.1 was launched last year and I doubt that the author would use an older version.

Comment: Oh, [it does apparently](https://owncloud.org/blog/owncloud-server-8-1-will-not-support-windows-as-server-platform-natively/#update), thanks:D